# System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled HResult=-2146233079 Message=Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to use Selenium Grid and C# to remotely control a Chrome browser. It used to work but since I installed a new Windows image on my machine B, it does not anymore. However, I am able to use Selenium locally on both computers, so I think it is not a chromedriver problem. For remote control, I run the following commands in machine A and machine B respectively:

```
java -jar C:\Users\FlcUser\Downloads\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar -role hub -host 10.1.1.14

java -Dwebdrive.chrome.drive="C:\Temp\chromedriver.exe" -jar C:\Temp\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar -role node -hub http://10.1.1.14:4444/grid/register
```

The node is successfully registered and then I run this C# code (I don't know if what I have commented is necessary but it doesn't change the error):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        //options.BinaryLocation = "C:\\Temp\\chromedriver.exe";
        IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.1.1.14:4444/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

I get this error:

> Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

I have read a lot about it, and I tried many things. I updated everything. I've made sure that my chromedriver version is compatible with my browser and I also have the last version of Java (https://java.com/en/download/, in both machines).

These are the logs I get in cmd:

Machine A:

```
17:48:23.746 INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://10.24.25.237:19016
17:50:19.814 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {}}
17:50:35.155 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=2dac93b3-8952-4c62-bcee-3c5febe21545, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5, platformName=WIN10, platform=WIN10}
```

Machine B:

```
21:48:31.497 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
"browserName": "chrome",
"goog:chromeOptions": {}}
21:48:31.497 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

And this is the exception Visual Studio throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-11-06T11:58:47'
System info: host: 'FLCOMPACT', ip: '10.1.1.25', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown (SessionNotCreated)
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
       at SeleniumPrueba.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\SeleniumDemo\SeleniumPrueba\Program.cs:line 21
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Finally, I have tried the same with other computers and I got the same error, so I am doing wrong. I think it is related with Java or chromedriver because I used to run this VS Code solution without problems. I updated also the libraries in Visual Studio via NuGet.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the command you have used to start the *Selenium Grid Node* which instead of being:

```
java -Dwebdrive.chrome.drive="C:\Temp\chromedriver.exe" -jar C:\Temp\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar -role node -hub http://10.1.1.14:4444/grid/register
```

Should have been:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/Temp/chromedriver.exe -jar C:/Temp/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar -role node -hub http://10.1.1.14:4444/grid/register
```

**Note A**: The *Key* is **`webdriver.chrome.driver`** but not `webdrive.chrome.drive`

**Note B**: Ensure that the *ChromeDriver* binary on the *Grid Node* is placed at `C:/Temp/`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My mistake writing this command without the "r" here. However, I run it right and the result is the same. Same error... sometimes instead of this "Unable to create new service" exception what happens is that it never open the browser and there is a time out when executing new RemoteWebDriver() method

Comment: **Clean** the _Project Working Space_ through your IDE and Build the project with required dependencies and execute your test, you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, I clean the solution, even create a very simple project with only these two lines. I changed selenium version 141.5 to 141.0 as it was the C# libraries that I had installed in my IDE. I've tried the same code but in local in the node (machine B) and it opens the browser successfully...

Comment: No, it works executing the same action but in local: instead of new RemoteWebDriver I write new ChromeDriver and I run it on Machine B without Selenium RC. To make sure chromedriver is not the problem...